Regex not capturing as expected
I am using QRegularExpression (Qt C++ library), and I want to extract the word ABC from a string as follows (Yes the slash quote is in the string):
\"ABC\" <DEF>

which as a C++ QString literal would be:
QString subject = "\\\"ABC\\\" <DEF>";

I have defined the following QRegularExpression:
QRegularExpression regex("\\\"([^\\]*)\\\"");

But the regex will not match the string literal above!  I've tried it in a couple of online RegEx testers (like this) and it works fine!  But in C++ the capture group is always empty.
What's wrong with the above?  I suspect something with all of the escapes (\) but can't see it.

Update: I also tried the following raw string literal with same result:

QRegularExpression regex(R""([^\\]*)"");



Update:
This must be a QRegularExpression bug...the following workaround will suffice, but I'll leave the question open in case someone can explain why the above doesn't work.
QStringList pieces=subject.split("\\\"");
if (pieces.size() >= 3) cap=pieces.at(1);


FWIW, when dealing with regex's, use a raw string literal instead of the old school string literal.  Makes them much easier to read and understand

"\"ABC\" <DEF>" doesn't look like right literal. It would produce string like this: "ABC" <DEF>

@Yksisarvinen You are right, the StackOverflow editor is causing me to add even more escapes.  Hopefully looks right now

@NathanOliver I tried raw string literal (as shown above) but same result

No, I didn't meant StackOverflow at all. C++ will interpret "\"ABC\" <DEF>" as a const char [12] containing "ABC" <DEF>\0. And now your example won't event compile. If you want \"ABC\" <DEF> with the slashes in a string literal, you need more slashes: QString x = "\\\"ABC\\\" <DEF>". Or easier with raw sting literal: R"(\"ABC\" <DEF>)"

@Yksisarvinen I updated SO post...now looks right.  Problem remains (just fighting the SO editor)

I'm starting to think this is a bug in QRegularExpression...

Recommendation: Witte question titles that contain information people can use to recognize your question as possibly being relevant to their searches. For example, you would not be asking this question if the regex was capturing as expected, to the only information in the title is the question has something to do with regex.

@TSG You are forgetting that C++ strings and regexes both need escaping. So to match a single blackslash with a regex you need a quadruple backslash in your string literal (or a double backslash in a raw string literal).

@john i think the raw literal regex is OK with a syntax. the raw literal version should work. it might be a bug indeed.

@john I'm not sure I agree/understand your response, I would need a quadruple backslash to represent a single backslash?  Can you post link to doc/ further info?

@TSG "\\\\" is a string of length 2, because in a C++ string literal backslashes must be escaped. In a regex a backslash is also an escape character, so to match a single backslash you need two backslashes. Put that together and you should see that to match a single blackslash you need four backslashes in your C++ string literal.

@TSG For documentation see the QT documentation on regexes. See the fourth example in the section 'Introduction' which is exactly the example I gave above, four backslashes match a single backslash.

In a regex a backslash needs escaping, so to match the string \ you need a regex \\. In a C++ string literal backslashes also need escaping, so to represent the regex \\ as a string literal you need "\\\\".
It's the necessity for two distinct layers of escaping that you are missing in your examples above.
Reference - see fourth example which deals with exactly this situation.

But the question shows that each slash is ALREADY properly escaped per C++.  Your post above says you need to QUADRUPLE slash to create a SINGLE slash...Can you post a specific Qt code sample that will work, showing quadruple slash?  Because the regex in the question works fine on online regex testing tools (see link in question), but in Qt with QRegularExpression is does NOT work.  And it is properly escaped per C++.

@TSG I don't know how I can explain this any better. Of course online regexes don't need a quadruple slash because the string you enter in an online web site is not a C++ string literal. It's because your string in your code is both a C++ string literal AND a regex that it needs to be doubly escaped (i.e. a quadruple backslash).

@TSG I don't have access to Qt so I can't produce sample code. However I posted a link to an example from the Qt documentation that showed exactly what I said above. If you don't believe the Qt documentation then how about just trying it yourself?

@TSG This is the point. Backslashes in C++ string literals need escaping. Backslashes in regexes need escaping. These are not the same escaping mechanism, they are separate. So you have to escape a backslash twice. So one backslash becomes two (first escape) and two backslashes become four (second escape).

Your QRegularExpression regex("\\\"([^\\]*)\\\"") is currently matching any character except \.
Change to QRegularExpression regex("\\\"([^\\\"]*)\\\"");

Welcome to StackOverflow! Please take some time to take the [tour] around the site and read [answer] to learn more about how things work here.

That will include the slash in the capture, which I don't want
